# Symfony2 - passing an object from Event Listener to Controller

Tags: symfony, controller

I have an Event Listener that finds an entity object in the database an checks whether current user is authorized for it. I need this object further in Controller, so my question is: **what is the best way to pass an object from Event listener to Controller**?

I have several options, but none of them is good enough.

1. In Controller, using repository to fetch the same object from database second time - which is actually less coupled but produces additional DB query.
2. Serializing object in Event Listener and passing it to Controller in request.
3. Making a service that will `set()` object in Event Listener and `get()` in Controller - but it looks like architectural flaw to assign service for such purposes.

Maybe anyone has better solution?

Comment: how does the application know if the current user is authorized for it?

Comment: By registering the event listener to service container and than use the service container in controller? [Link](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/event_dispatcher/introduction.html#connecting-listeners)

Comment: right.. I think the answer is already given.

Comment: i protect my objects with custom voters: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/voters.html

Comment: @Frankbeen: actually, this is not about authorization, but yes, I use security voters, and still need some processing before and after, so it looks like job for Pre-filters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Event Listener is a service like any other service. You can save your object to a protected member of your service, create a getter for it and in the controller get this service and retrieve the objet using the getter

Comment: Indeed... But isn't this implicit in some way? I mean, Event Listener is not responsible for storing objects.